# Display click-through overlay on Android, e.g. baseline grid

Tags: android, ui-design

I want to see if my application conforms with the Material Design [guidelines regarding metrics](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-baseline-grids) and adjust where required. For that I'd wish to have a 8dp square grid or 4dp baseline grid drawn over my whole window without intercepting touch events, so that I could tap and scroll as usual (think of "Show layout bounds" mode in dev options). It should look something like this:

[image: baseline overlay]

Questions:

1. How do I put such view on the top of everything and make it "click-through"?
2. Or maybe there are already tools / libraries / snippets for achieving this? **UPD** This one is answered, thank you! Question 1 remains open for curiosity reasons

Comment: Not an appropriate question for SO but see: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faizmalkani.keylines&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is what I use](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.inmite.android.gridwichterle)

Note: I have no affiliation to the author of the app, it's just what I use extensively in my own development.

Comment: Thank you! Will compare to the app named above

Comment: Oh, and it is open source! Nifty!

Answer (score 2):

**UPD2**: The app referenced by @john actually has [their sources open.](https://github.com/inmite/android-grid-wichterle) Looks like this snippet does it. So simple.

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);

final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

wm.addView(myOverlayView, lp);
```